# Font Color in Rich Text field

Tags: redactor, richtext

Is it possible to get the Font Color plugin into Redactor?

I tried adding it to my redactor json file as below but no luck.

```
{
buttons: ['html','fontcolor','table','formatting','bold','italic','alignment','unorderedlist','horizontalrule','orderedlist','outdent', 'indent','link','image','video'],
plugins: ['fullscreen','video','table','fontcolor'],
toolbarFixedBox: true
}
```

Font Color Redactor Plugin - http://imperavi.com/redactor/plugins/font-color/

I'm not sure what the correct process is to get it working in my Craft admin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The plugin doesn't come with Craft. You have to manually install it with a Craft plugin, but luckily this is easy to do:

- Set up your new Craft plugin (→ ["Plugin Development - Setting Things Up"](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/setting-things-up))
- Download the Redactor plugin and copy it to craft/plugins/myplugin/resources/
- Load the Redactor plugin JS file from the init function:
  `craft()->templates->includeJsResource('myplugin/redactorplugin.js');`

Comment: Thanks Carlcs, i didn't realise how easy it was to set up a little plugin like that.